# How would one convert a razor loop into a Vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, .net, razor, vue.js

I'm attempting to take a very dumb vue component and move more of the code (written in razor) into the component itself (to keep it as modular as possible).

Currently the component is more of a container where razor loops through a list of communities and renders out some html server-side.  That html is then passed through a slot into the component and styled.

Ideally, I would like to find a way to render only the bare minimum through razor, and instead move as much of the logic into the component as possible. For example, I know vue offers a mechanism for looping through data (v-for), however in this case, I'm not quite sure how to pass the data into the component in such a way as to utilize that.

Being new to vue (as I think most of us are), I'm still getting the hang of passing server-side data through to components.  I've tried creating props, but the complexity of the data being generated has thrown me off a bit.  I'm hoping someone here can shine a little light on the best way to approach this problem!

Thanks in advance!

index.cshtml:

```
<community-list>
      @foreach (var region in regions)
      {
          var regPage = region.Pages.FirstOrDefault();
          if (regPage == null)
          {
              continue;
          }
          string isActive = "";
          int communityCount = 0;
          var cities = region.Children;
          for (int i = 0; i < cities.Count; i++) {
              communityCount += cities[i].Pages.Count;
          }
          if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated && !Model.IsPreview) {
              var email = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
              isActive = CompanyName.Core.Models.Users.IsRegionSubscribed(email, region.Name) ? "active" : "";
          }
        <div class="community container primary @isActive" data-name="@region.Name">
          <figure style="background-image: url('/assets/images/@regPage.GetAttributeValue("HeroImage")');"></figure>
          <h3>@regPage.GetAttributeValue("Title")</h3>
          <p>@(communityCount.ToString()) New Home Communities</p>
          <custom-button destination="@regPage.URL" appearance="primary" type="link" size="extra-large" text="Find New Homes in @stateName"></custom-button>
        </div>
      }
    </community-list>
```

CommunityList.vue

```
<template>
  <section class="community-list">
    <slot></slot>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CommunityList',
  };
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  -- styling here --
</style>
```

**Update**

**------**

To clarify further:

Assuming it's the proper approach, I would like to pull the html in the razor loop out of the slot and place it into the component.  Remove the slot altogether, and take the data from razor and populate the html in the component with the values that are returned from razor.

It seems to me the more html and logic I can move into the component the better.

Perhaps something like:

index.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var region in regions) {
  var foo = region.foo;
  var bar = region.bar;
}
<community-list foo="@foo" bar="@bar"></community-list>
```

CommunityList.vue

```
<template>
  <section v-for="region in regions">
    <p>{{ foo }}</p>
    <p>{{ bar }}</p>
  </section>
</template>
```

I'm not quite sure how best to approach this from a vue-centric manner. If I converted the razor to simply spit out a list of vars to use like above, how would I then take that data, pass it into the component, and loop through it within the vue component itself (something like the example above)?  In the case above, I'm sure this won't work - but I imagine there must be some way to accomplish what I'm thinking of somehow?

(Or am I just approaching this the wrong way altogether?)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to render the data into a  tag with razor, into a global variable. When you set up your vue component, use that global variable to set up the `data` function.

Comment: Maybe I'm not quite understanding how to hook into the loop in razor with the component's vue loop.  I'm not quite sure how best to approach this from a vue-centric manner.

If I converted the razor to simply spit out a list of vars to use, for example:

@foreach (var region in regions) { var foo=region.foo; var bar=region.bar; }

How would I then take that data, pass it into the component, and loop through it within the vue component itself? (Essentially I want to move all the html out of the slot into the component and populate the values in the html with the data in the razor loop.)

Comment: Instead of doing that, output it as json, and then when you create your main Vue component you do:
`new Vue({data: myDataInJsonForm, ....})`